# Why does starting a %-type comment after "\end{comment}" cause problems?

Tags: comments

Not that big a deal, but why does putting a %-type comment in the same line after `\end{comment}` cause problems?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  

\usepackage{comment}
% \usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
 
\begin{document}
asdfasdf

\begin{comment}
dsdf
\end{comment}  %comment begins line 46



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming the tex file is called `main.tex`, the input lines

```
...
\end{comment}  %comment begins
...
\end{document}
```

generate the following, somewhat incomprehensible prompt:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> main.tex
            
?
```

What has happened is that LaTeX has gotten to the end of the file without ever "seeing" `\end{comment}` and , by extension, `\end{document}`. What's going on?

*By design*, a `comment` environment is allowed to contain pretty much any arbitrary material, including code that could change the meaning, i.e., the so-called category code, of `\` (backslash), `%`,   (whitespace), `{`, `}`, and all other characters, whether or not these characters are "TeX-special" by default. Thus, in order to determine when and where the comment material ends, one mustn't rely on TeX's usual input processing subsystem, which does assume that `\`, `{`, `}`, `%`,   etc have certain meanings. Instead, some fairly stringent formal requirements have to be imposed on the literal contents of the input string. The author of the `comment` package has decided that the termination marker *must* consist of the literal string

```
\end{comment}
```

*and nothing else*; i.e., nothing else is allowed to be on that input line, either before or after `\end{comment}`.

I suppose that one could point out that this requirement represents a *sufficient condition* for deciding where the comment material ends, and that a *necessary condition* could be formulated in a less stringent way, e.g., to allow a `%`-type comment to occur on the same line as `\end{comment}`. It's quite likely that one could come up with such a weaker necessary condition. Clearly, though, the author of the `comment` package decided that this wasn't necessary (pun intended).

Answer (score -2):

If the \end{comment} is on the \begin{comment} line, it is considered as a comment.
So the \begin{comment} have no end.

Comment: Could you please rephrase and explain, how your answer relates  to the code the OP posted?

Comment: The OP's question was why `\end{comment} %comment` fails, not why `\begin{comment} \end{comment}` fails.

Comment: '\end {comment}% comment' is a comment and therefore inactive. So \begin {comment} at the beginning of the line has no corresponding \end {comment}. All code that follow is comment, \end{document} is comment and the compilation fail because the document has no \end.

Comment: texdoc comment 
Usage:
The ‘comment’ environment is defined by default: all text included between
\begin{comment}
...
\end{comment}
is discarded.
The opening and closing commands should appear *on a line of their own*. No starting
spaces, nothing after it.

Comment: So it's not that `\end{comment}` on the `\begin{comment}` line is the problem.  The problem is something else on the `\end{comment}` line.